# Can I automatically set client-side hook scripts for a new working copy in tortoisesvn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I just started using to client-side hook scripts and I wondered whether I can automatically set them when I check out a new working copy. As far as I understand they are working copy specific and can only be set via Settings->Hook scripts.
I tend to create and delete WCs rather frequently and setting the hook scripts manually every time seems a bit tedious. After all, automation is what hook scripts are all about, right?

Am I missing something here or am I maybe just using them wrong?

I use **TortoiseSVN 1.9.4**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseSVN lets you configure properties (versioned with the rest of your project) which specify client-side hook scripts to be associated with the project.

See https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-tsvn-props

These will be applied to anyone who uses TortoiseSVN with your project, so be sure to set it up in such a way that it's not specific to your workstation/user account.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!